# Meaning of scale indicator in image generated by fiducial::PoseDrawer?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the meaning of "scale 0.25 meters"?

[image: image description]

The picture has been generated with package fiducial in object_recognition stack. See function `PoseDrawer` in [fiducial.cpp](http://https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/browser/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/object_recognition/fiducial/src/fiducial.cpp). What came to my mind is that the vectors representing the three axes are of length 0.25m. But alas that's just a guess.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9793/meaning-of-scale-indicator-in-image-generated-by-fiducial::posedrawer?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you are correct. From the code:

```
414 void PoseDrawer(cv::Mat& drawImage, const cv::Mat& K, const PoseRT& pose)
415 {
416   Point3f z(0, 0, 0.25);
417   Point3f x(0.25, 0, 0);
418   Point3f y(0, 0.25, 0);
419   Point3f o(0, 0, 0);
```

The length of the drawn arrows is 0.25 meters for scale.

---

Originally posted by [Helen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1033/helen/) with karma: 261 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1